# mysql variables and loop in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, loops

I 'm facing a problem when trying to use a timestamp variable in stored procedure's loop. In the following, gtime is a TIMESTAMP input variable and samples is an INTEGER input variable

```
...
DECLARE t TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE i,step INT DEFAULT 0;

SET t = gtime;

myLabel: LOOP
    IF i = samples THEN
        LEAVE myLabel;
    END IF;

    SELECT a, b FROM myTable 
        WHERE myField = 1
        AND g_time > t
        AND g_time < '2011-09-06 00:00:09';

        SET i = i + 1;      
        SET t = t + 1500;   

    ITERATE myLabel;
END LOOP myLabel;
...
```

While the i change its value properly and the loop is executed for "samples" times, the t is not affected and thus the SELECT statement does not work well. The t variable has always its original value.

Any ideas why the t variable remains the same? I tried using while statement as well but the problem remains the same. Is it forbidden to use variables in SELECT that are changing withing the loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an integer `1500` to a `TIMESTAMP`.  To perform date arithmetic you need to use `INTERVAL`:

```
SET t = t + INTERVAL 25 MINUTE;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. The t remains the same. I tried also the    

SET t = TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 60, t);

but with no luck. What is going wrong? Is it a timestamp format issue ?